# Why does everything I've made in Unity begin to vanish when I get close to it?

Tags: unity, 3d, camera, frustum-culling

I've attempted looking into this via. the Unity Manual, and even posts on the Unity forum, although I've found nothing. I have already tried checking Occlusion Culling and general Object Culling.

I've skimmed through the settings as well, and found nothing I figured was related to why my camera is behaving like this.
(near the bottom, where it abruptly cuts off.)

[image: Camera behavior]

Answer (score 3):

In Unity 2021.3, you can adjust the clipping planes for the Scene view like this:

[image]

1. In the Scene view, click the Camera button
2. Deselect "Dynamic Clipping"
3. Edit the Near and Far clipping planes as needed (in your case, reduce the Near plane).

The procedure may vary in other versions of Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the cameras clipping planes:

[image]

if you decrease the near plane, parts close to the camera will be rendered, its mostly there so that if for example, you put the camera inside the head of a player, the model doesnt block the view.

Comment: Note that the GPU depth buffer covers the range from near to far clipping plane. If you decrease the near plane, you should ideally also decrease the far plane (eg divide both by 10).  Otherwise, if the range is too large, you can get z-fighting issues.

Comment: The issue in the screenshot seems to he with the scene view camera in editor, rather than the camera component rendering the game view.

Comment: @DMGregory true, didn't think about that, in that case I don't know. But if it doesnt effect the game I don't see why it would matter that much. The camera likely clips to avoid the view being blocked.

Comment: You don't see why it should matter if the person editing the level can't see what they're doing?

Comment: You can still see it, It's hard to tell how large the objects in the scene are, but surely moving to a different position would stop the clipping, there isn't a lot of detail in the question about what he's tried so its hard to tell.

Comment: If it is a big issue, this may fix it: https://forum.unity.com/threads/scene-editor-camera-is-cutting-off-my-objects.442259/

Comment: That looks like advice that would make a good answer post.